# C# variable scoping is not consistent

Tags: c#, scope

C# is quite nitpicky when it comes to variable scoping. How is it possible that it accepts the following code?

```
class Program
{
    int x = 0;

    void foo()
    {
        int x = 0;
        x = 1;
        
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

If you ask me, that's an obvious naming conflict. Still the compiler ([Visual Studio 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2010)) accepts it. Why?

Comment: You can refer to `x` and `this.x`, so there's no problem.

Comment: Actually that is consistent.   if you had just x=0 in the void foo() function then it would pick up the variable from x that you earlier defined.  Because you have int x = 0 in the method you have for all intents instantiated a new variable.   But if you look at the value of x outside of the foo method it will still be 0 because you are in a different scope then.

Comment: If you don't like being able to have a local variable with the same name as a class member, then you can get ReSharper and [have it prevent you from doing this](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/Local+variable+hides+member).

Comment: Yes, from your perspective it's naming conflict, but it's one for which a resolution has been predetermined by the language designers; the local variable takes precedence over the the instance variable.  The reason that the compiler accepts it is because it is valid within the language definition.  I suspect that the reason the precedence is defined is that it is fairly easy and intuitive to decide what to do with this situation.  For other cases (two local variables with overlapping scopes, etc.), it is less so and it is flagged as an error.

Comment: You might also find [Scope vs Declaration Space vs Lifetime](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/03/what-s-the-difference-part-two-scope-vs-declaration-space-vs-lifetime.aspx) interesting.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The rules for C# name hiding are quite complex. The language allows the case you mention, but disallows many similar cases. See

*[Simple names are not so simple, part one](http://ericlippert.com/2009/11/02/simple-names-are-not-so-simple/)*

for some information on this complicated subject.

To address your specific question: the compiler certainly could detect that conflict. In fact, it *does* detect that conflict:

```
class P
{
    int x;
    void M()
    {
        x = 123; // The author intends "this.x = 123;"
        int x = 0;
    }
}
```

The equivalent C++ program would be legal C++, because in C++ a local variable comes into scope at the point of its declaration.  In C#, a local variable is in scope throughout its entire block, and using it before its declaration is illegal. If you try compiling this program you get:

```
error CS0844: Cannot use local variable 'x' before it is declared.
The declaration of the local variable hides the field 'P.x'.
```

See: **the local declaration hides the field**. The compiler knows it. So why in your case is it not an *error* to hide a field?

Let's suppose for the sake of argument that it should be an error. Should this also be an error?

```
class B
{
    protected int x;
}

class D : B
{
    void M()
    {
        int x;
    }
}
```

The field x is *a member of D* via inheritance from B.  So this should also be an error, right?

Now suppose you have this program produced by Foo Corporation:

```
class B
{
}
```

and this program produced by Bar Corporation:

```
class D : B
{
    void M()
    {
        int x;
    }
}
```

That compiles. Now suppose Foo Corp updates their base class and ships a new version out to you:

```
class B
{
    protected int x;
}
```

You're telling me that **every derived class that contains a local variable named x should now fail to compile?**

That would be horrid. We have to allow local variables to shadow members.

And if we're going to allow locals to shadow members of base classes, it would seem awfully strange to not allow locals to shadow members of classes.

Comment: That's what's confusing me. Since C# disallows many of the naming conflicts that C/C++ do allow, I would expect this strictness for the above scenario too.

Comment: @NOPslider: I've added some text explaining why that would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 15):

This is not a naming conflict: in C#, local variables take precedence over instance variables with the same name, because their [*scope*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is narrower.

> When the compiler matches a name reference to a name declaration, it uses the matching declaration with the narrowest scope

See documentation on [Reference Matching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z4yz8w6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for detailed information on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

That’s normal.

In constructors I often use the same.

```
public Person(string name) {
  this.name = name;
}
```

Else it would be not possible to declare method parameters which are named like member variables.

Answer (score 1):

There is no naming conflict. The compiler always takes the `nearest`/least scope variable.

In this case, that’s the x variable you declare in `foo`.
Every variable can be accessed in a specific way, so there isn't any naming conflict.

If you want to access the outer x you can use `this.x`.

Comment: Is "nearest" literal?

Answer (score 1):

The C# 4.0 specification says this about scope hiding through nesting:

> **3.7.1.1 Hiding through nesting**

> Name hiding through nesting can occur as a result of nesting namespaces or types within namespaces, as a
> result of nesting types within classes or structs, and as a result of
> parameter and local variable declarations. In the example

```
class A {
    int i = 0;

    void F() {
        int i = 1;
    }

    void G() {
        i = 1;
    }
}
```

> within the F method, the instance variable i is hidden by the local
> variable i, but within the G method, i still refers to the instance
> variable.
>
> When a name in an inner scope hides a name in an outer
> scope, it hides all overloaded occurrences of that name.
>
> In the example

```
class Outer {
    static void F(int i) {}
    static void F(string s) {}

    class Inner
    {
        void G() {
            F(1);           // Invokes Outer.Inner.F
            F("Hello");     // Error
        }

        static void F(long l) {}
    }
}
```

> the call F(1) invokes the F declared in Inner because all outer
> occurrences of F are hidden by the inner declaration. For the same
> reason, the call F("Hello") results in a compile-time error.

Answer (score 0):

Because the rule is that if a conflict exists between a local variable and a class member, the local variable has higher precedence.

Answer (score 0):

This is not ambiguous. The local will be the variable that is assumed to be referred to in your function.  If you need to get the class variable, *this.x* allows the name resolution.