# First C# program with two Classes. Confused

Tags: c#, class

pretty new to programming and I'm a bit stuck. This is the first program I've written with two classes (in two seperate class files). I'll include all the code below. It's a program to play a dice game called Craps. My task is too create a method in the CrapsGame class that allows me to play the game over and over again until I decide to stop. But I'm having a little trouble working out how to correctly call the manyPlay() method. I'm not really sure what I'm doing. The program will play the game once by calling myCraps.play() but then won't go any further. If anyone else notices anything wrong with the code or anything that's bad practice then please point it out as I am very keen to learn. Thanks to anyone that takes the time to answer.

```
using System;

namespace Task4_7
{
    public class CrapsGame
    {
        string replay;
        private Craps myCraps;
        private CrapsGame newGame;


        public static void Main()
        {
            CrapsGame newGame = new CrapsGame();
            Craps myCraps = new Craps ();
            myCraps.play ();
            newGame.manyPlay ();
        }
        public void manyPlay() {
            string input; // declare local variable
            do {
                myCraps.play();
                replay:
                Console.Write("Would you like to play again? y/n");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (input == "y") {
                    replay = input;
                }
                else if (input == "n") {
                    replay = "n";
                }
                else {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n Erroneous input. Please enter y (yes) or n (no)");
                    goto replay;
                }
            }
            while(replay != "n");
        } 
    }
}





using System;

namespace Task4_7
{
    public class Craps
    {
        private Random randy;               // define randy as a Random class

        public Craps() {

            this.randy = new Random ();
        }

        public int oneThrow() {
            return randy.Next(6) + 1;        // pick a number from 1 to 6 and return this
        }
        public int throw2Dice() {
            int a, b, c;
            a = oneThrow ();
            b = oneThrow ();
            c = a + b;
            Console.WriteLine ("You threw a " + a + " and a " + b + " making " + c);
            return c;
        }
        public void play() {
            int result = throw2Dice ();
            switch (result) {
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine ("You lose! End of game!");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine ("You lose! End of game!");
                    break;
                case 12:
                    Console.WriteLine ("You lose! End of game!");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    Console.WriteLine ("You win! End of game!");
                    break;
                case 11:
                    Console.WriteLine ("You win! End of game!");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine ("Your point! Rolling again!");
                    throwPoint (result);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Console.WriteLine ("Your point! Rolling again!");
                    throwPoint (result);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Console.WriteLine ("Your point! Rolling again!");
                    throwPoint (result);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    Console.WriteLine ("Your point! Rolling again!");
                    throwPoint (result);
                    break;
                case 9:
                    Console.WriteLine ("Your point! Rolling again!");
                    throwPoint (result);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine ("Your point! Rolling again!");
                    throwPoint (result);
                    break;
            }
        }
        public void throwPoint(int result) {
            Throw:
            int a = throw2Dice();
            if (a == result) {
                Console.WriteLine ("You rolled the same score! You win!");
            } else if (a == 7) {
                Console.WriteLine ("You rolled a 7! You loose!");
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine ("You rolled a " + a + ". Rolling again!");
                goto Throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the first time i see someone using "goto" in C#

Comment: Don't use `goto`, it's evil. As for actual problems: you never initialize the `myCraps` field and you don't want a `newGame` field. I think you're confusing the local variables inside the `Main` method with your class's instance fields.

Comment: As an aside, if you want a help code reviewing your code, check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Don't use Main any more the necessary it is evel. It is not object orientated. Main should have one line `new Application.run();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
Craps myCraps = new Craps();
```

You are hiding variable of class `CrapsGame` with a local variable of `Main` method. Simply change it to

```
myCraps = new Craps();
```

and it should work.

**EDIT**

and change `myCraps` declaration to `static`, of course.

**EDIT2**

Scope of variables: [C# variable scoping not consistent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330601/c-sharp-variable-scoping-not-consistent)

Comment: You should explain more *why* this was the problem. What was really happening. Or maybe link to a tutorial which explains "hiding".

Comment: Don't make the variables static, fix the real problem. Main is not object orientated. Use it only to bootstrap your start-up object.

Comment: Well... it actually is hard to explain all the mistakes in different way than writing the program again from scratch. I'll do it later when I have more time. In the meantime link to SO similar question.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is put your `Main` method in a seperate file.For example you can use three files: `Program.cs,` `CrapsGame.cs`, `Craps.cs`. To do this just add a new class file,and move your main method to new Class file. Second, never use goto.Instead use while loop like this,

```
public void throwPoint(int result) {
   while(true)
   {
      int a = throw2Dice();
       if (a == result) {
           Console.WriteLine ("You rolled the same score! You win!");
           break;
       } else if (a == 7) {
          Console.WriteLine ("You rolled a 7! You loose!");
          break;
      } else {
        Console.WriteLine ("You rolled a " + a + ". Rolling again!");
    }
  }
}
```

Many play method:

```
public void manyPlay() {
    string input; // declare local variable
    myCraps.play();
    while(true) {
        Console.Write("Would you like to play again? y/n");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (input == "y") {
            myCraps.play();
        }
        else if (input == "n") {
            break;
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("\n Erroneous input. Please enter y (yes) or n (no)");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like you where creating a game for use by the game iterator, but it needs to create a game for each iteration. So I delete some code: all the class variables have to go, variables should be as local as possible.

```
using System;

namespace Task4_7
{
    public class CrapsGame
    {  
        public static void Main()
        {
            new Craps ().play ();
            new CrapsGame().manyPlay ();
        }

        public void manyPlay() {
            string replay;
            string input; // declare local variable
            do {
                new Craps().play();
                replay:
                Console.Write("Would you like to play again? y/n");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (input == "y") {
                    replay = input;
                }
                else if (input == "n") {
                    replay = "n";
                }
                else {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n Erroneous input. Please enter y (yes) or n (no)");
                    goto replay;
                }
            }
            while(replay != "n");
        } 
    }
}
```

Now fix that loop: no gotos. You need a loop in a loop, as you have but don't build your own loops.

Then if Craps.play() returned a score. You could add a class variable to accumulate the score.

Answer (score -2):

Change replay to boolean and make set it to true if input is y and false if input is n.

Then change your main method.

```
  public static void Main()
{
    CrapsGame newGame = new CrapsGame();
    Craps myCraps = new Craps ();

    while (replay == true) {
       myCraps.play ();
       newGame.manyPlay ();
    }
}
```