# Overwriting variable in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables, void, overwrite

I'm making a script in Unity using C#. I'm trying to use the Update() method to detect once the Camera position is past a certain point and then Instantiate an object into the scene and overwrite the variable "x" to something else so this only happens once. 
The problem is I cant overwrite this "x" variable.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour{
    public GameObject GroundSprite;
    public int x = 1;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (((Camera.main.transform.position.x) < -4) && ( x == 1)) 
        {
            Instantiate(GroundSprite, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            int x = 2;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Remove `int` in your method. Simply `x = 2;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# variable scoping not consistent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330601/c-sharp-variable-scoping-not-consistent)

Comment: As @dymanoid mentioned the problem is with the scope!
You are overwriting the member variable with a local variable!

Comment: @Ruzihm not a 100%. I think the original poster doesn't know how to use variables. In the question you've linked the question was why this is possible.

Comment: @csabinho this post's asker and likely future visitors need an explanation of how scoping affects variables that share the same name and the linked post provides that directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove int from below code, your value will be overwritten.

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (((Camera.main.transform.position.x) < -4) && ( x == 1)) 
    {
        Instantiate(GroundSprite, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
         //int x = 2;
           x=2;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems this did not fix the problem as the void Update() method is called 60 times per second, and it keeps instantiating the object. If it worked x would be equal to 2, and the If statement would not permit the object to be instantiated more than once

Comment: @jay What object(s) is/are `NewBehaviourScript` attached to?

Comment: @Ruzihm it is attached to GroundSprite

Comment: I fixed the problem! Seems I caused a never ending loop of instantiating objects because the newly instantiated object had a script attached to it that would instantiate a clone. Thanks!