# Why does Unity throw error CS0136 here while Visual Studio 2019 doesn't?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Suppose you have this code in Unity (adapted from [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9330601/1193647)):

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        int x = 0;
        void foo() {
            int x = 0;
            x = 1;
            Debug.Log(x);
        }
    }
}
```

In Visual Studio 2019, the compiler happily accepts this code, which makes sense given the explanation provided at the SO answer.

However Unity throws error [CS0136](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0136), with the message:

> error CS0136: A local or parameter named 'x' cannot be declared in
> this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to
> define a local or parameter

This seems to reference local scopes  (not local functions), which indeed cannot redefine variables declared in the containing scope.

Local functions do seem to work in Unity (I can call foo after changing the variable names and get the expected Debug.Log output), so I'm wondering why this difference in compilers exists (and if there's acknowledgement/explanation for that difference somewhere in the docs).

Why does Unity throw an error here?

Unity Player Settings are set to Mono for Scripting backend and .NET Standard 2.0 for API compatibility (if that makes a difference).

**EDIT:** Unity version is 2019.3.0f6.

Comment: Local functions were introduced in C# 7 - I *believe* that Unity only supports C# 6 (but I don't know for sure, and can't find a suitable reference, hence why I'm posting a comment)

Comment: You may be able to configure Unity to work with C# 7 (e.g. [see here](https://gist.github.com/pflannery/9a03c174df22098f6904ead5230cfc94)) but I suspect this is more trouble than it's worth...

Comment: I guess I'm confused because I'd expect that in this case, local functions wouldn't work, but they do. Also, I could only find that C#7 support started with Unity 2018 (I should have stated that I'm running Unity 2019), but requires .net 4.x profile.

Comment: Apologies - you did address this in your question and I'm afraid I failed to read it fully. Um - in that case, I'm afraid I don't know. Your code looks perfectly valid if that's any consolation? :)

Comment: For me VisualStudio shows the same error ... and it should! Local functions behave a bit different than the normal hiding scope of methods with the same name variable. checkout the duplicate link where this is explained better but in short: In a local function all variables declared in the parent method scope are also available so you get a naming conflict for `x`.

Comment: @derHugo I don't think that question is similar at all. Firstly, their first code compiles and runs, as does mine. So I'm not sure why your version of VS throws an error, but it definitely shouldn't. The question here however is entirely unrelated to the other question (which nests the call and expects recursivity). My function names are not the same, which is what that question is about.

Comment: @Kolichikov if you set your VS 2019 project the same way (library targeting  .NET Standard 2.0) it will behave the same way too...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yea, I realized this after I asked on the roslyn github and found out that this was a c# 8 feature. I was confused because I expected Unity to create a project that matched that .net standard 2.0 profile with the corresponding langversion, but it's set to `latest`, which from the docs seems to suggest that it will use the latest version available to the compiler.

Comment: you function names are not the same but `x` is the same in your local function as in the parent function and as I said the variables of `Start` are also present in the scope of `foo` and therefore you get a naming conflict for `x` .. it is not hiding the outer `x` ... I just copy pasted your code into a new script and VS [throws exactly the same compiler error as you see in Unity](https://imgur.com/XC7Nkrs) ... I don't know why yours does not ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the result of how Unity creates the csproj file, specifically the Language version it sets, and the mismatch between C# 8 and 7.3.

As a reference, this feature (hiding variable names in local functions) was introduced in C# 8. Here's the [github link](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-8.0/shadowing-in-nested-functions.md)  to the change. As to why the Unity project uses C# 8, my best guess is below.

If you open up the `csproj` file created by Unity, you'll find

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

as well as a target to 4.7.1 (regardless of what your Unity project settings are)

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

and a defined constant: `CSHARP_7_3_OR_NEWER`, which is a [Unity constant](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html)

From the [C# docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) on language versions, you can find that while .NET Standard 2.0 defaults to C# 7.3, the above `<LangVersion>` value seems to imply that the language version used in VS will be the latest one it has access to. Here's the relevant bit from the above link:

> latest    - The compiler accepts syntax from the latest released version of
>   the compiler (including minor version).

So in the end, it looks like if you've installed a compiler that supports C# 8, the Unity project will be setup in a way that allows that, even though it looks like internally, Unity is still using C# 7.3.